# Idiomatic alternative to C's `system` function in Zig

Tags: c, zig

Is there a way to make a system call in Zig, other than using a cImport?
right now I've got it to work with something like that:

```
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("stdlib.h");
});

// ...

const result: c_int = c.system(cmd);
```

While this works fine, I'd like to do it "the zig way", without having to import stuff from C.

Comment: `system` is a not a system call, it is a function. You can to call a syscall _or_ you want to call a C function? System calls are implemented by pushing _specific_ data to _specific_ registers and then calling _specific_ assembly to trigger interrupt, see `man syscall`. It would be much simpler to re-use a C wrapper for that.

Comment: ah, okay, thanks for the clarification. Then I guess my question is, is there an equivalent of the system-function in zig, that I can use to execute a command?

Comment: Note that `system` isn't really "idiomatic" in C either. It's OK for throwaway scripts, but for "serious" programs you'd use your platforms process API (i.e. `fork/exec`, `CreateProcess`, ... or a suitable abstraction thereof).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternative to using C's `system()` function is to use [`ChildProcess`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ChildProcess) in Zig:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    const result = try std.ChildProcess.exec(.{
        .allocator = allocator,
        .argv = &[_][]const u8{ "date" },
    });
    defer {
        allocator.free(result.stdout);
        allocator.free(result.stderr);
    }

    std.log.info("stdout: {s}", .{ result.stdout });
    std.log.info("stderr: {s}", .{ result.stderr });
}
```

This prints:

```
$ zig build run
info: stdout: Tue, Aug  8, 2023  1:45:02 PM

info: stderr:
```

Comment: Just a note that std.ChildProcess.exec has been replaced by std.ChildProcess.run